# PHP - Send option to style.php using get_option

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am not sure how to formulate the question so I start saying that in my plugin folder I have 2 files:

1 - "index.php"

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );

function my_admin_setting() {
    include('includes/my_admin.php');
    include('css/wp-admin.php');
}

function custom_admin_actions() {
    add_menu_page("Customise-Admin", "Custom-Admin", 1, "Custom_Admin", "my_admin_setting");
    add_submenu_page('Custom_Admin', 'About', 'About', 1, 'info', "my_admin_info");

}

function my_admin_theme_style() {

    wp_register_style('my-admin-theme', plugins_url('css/wp-admin.php', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('my-admin-theme');
}


add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_theme_style');
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_theme_style');
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_admin_actions');


add_option( 'my_adminbar_color', 'red' );
```

2 - wp_admin.php (style)

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/css');
?>

<?php 
$blue = '#0e70d1';
$dkgray = '#333';
$dkgreen = '#008400';
?>
<?php $myplugin_color = get_option( 'my_adminbar_color' ); ?>

#wpadminbar {

  background-color: <?php echo $myplugin_color;?> !important;
}
```

The problem here is that I am trying to pass an option to a php style. When I don't insert the "get_option" function my custom style is visible however, as soon as I pass the value the style is not rendered anymore.

I can see that the option is passed to the style file as the css code get printed in the plugin page, instead of running the code as CSS seems that it becomes formatted as normal text.

Could someone explain to me why this happens? And How could I pass the option to my style file?

Comment: [get_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) returns false if the value is not set. You can add a default value like `get_option( 'my_adminbar_color', '#ABCDEF' )`.

Comment: but I have set it in the index page add_option( 'my_adminbar_color', 'red' ); I can see the value red being output, but the style stops working. As soon as I delete the get_option function the style works again.

Comment: oh ok, you're calling the wp-admin.php file directly, so Wordpress is not loaded inside that file, and `get_option` is not defined. I'm gonna try and give a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much d79. When I don't  call wp-admin.php directly and I delete the get_option from wp-admin.php, the style works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the wp-admin.php file directly, so Wordpress is not loaded inside that file, and `get_option` is not defined.

This could be a solution (without the use of external file like *wp-admin.php*):

```
function my_admin_theme_style () {
    $blue    = '#0e70d1';
    $dkgray  = '#333';
    $dkgreen = '#008400';
    $myplugin_color = get_option( 'my_adminbar_color', 'red' );
    return "
        body {
            background-color: $myplugin_color !important;
        }
    ";
}

function add_my_style_to_admin () {
    wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', my_admin_theme_style() );
}

function add_my_style_to_login () {
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    echo my_admin_theme_style();
    echo '</style>';
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_style_to_admin');
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_style_to_login');
```

I had to make 2 functions because `admin_enqueue_scripts` and `login_enqueue_scripts` work in different ways.

Comment: Thank you, this is working.. Now I have an issue that when I submit my option value to get updated, it works however, I have to submit two times for the settings to be rendered. See the edit in your answer.

Comment: I don't think we should edit this aswer with another question. However I think the problem is that you're setting the new color after the styles have already been loaded. You should call `update_option` before calling or inside the `my_admin_theme_style` function.

Comment: OK thank you so much for your help, and sorry for the edit. I will try to follow your advice

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. Hope you figure it out, otherwise maybe add another question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the specifics of wordpress, but if you're trying to apply

```
#wpadminbar {

  background-color: <?php echo $myplugin_color;?> !important;
}
```

as a style, you need to wrap it in `<style>` tags.  So it would be

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/css');
?>

<?php 
$blue = '#0e70d1';
$dkgray = '#333';
$dkgreen = '#008400';
?>
<?php $myplugin_color = get_option( 'my_adminbar_color' ); ?>

<style>
#wpadminbar {

  background-color: <?php echo $myplugin_color;?> !important;
}
</style>
```

Not 100% confident on this, but it's my best guess.

Comment: I have tried this it works however the style is rendered just on the plugin page and not in all the dashboard. Thank you anyway for the fast response